# Connecting a Dockerized Ruby on Rails WebApp to an external Azure Hosted Postgres Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, azure, docker

First, let me say, I have tried so many different search terms for weeks now and have not found an answer. So, the title to this question is very specific to what I am needing to do.

**Background that can be skipped**

This webapp is one of many for a non-profit organization. We are moving all our web resources to Microsoft Azure to reduce overall costs. We currently have our databases transferred to Azure, and all Ruby on Rails WebApps running on Heroku. We are needing to change our WebApps to be Dockerized as it seems Azure will soon not support Ruby as a stand alone language. Once they are Dockerized, we will need to deploy to Azure.

**What Needs to Happen**

We are planning on scalability, so each WebApp will need to be able to have multiple instances running all of which connect to central databases hosted on Azure.

This RoR app, currently running on Heroku, connects to 2 different databases; one for member logins and the other for the app specific data. This is because there are multiple sites that utilize the same central member login database and have their own app specific database.

Once the RoR app is in a Docker image, it should have the template for the RoR code as well as SideKiq and Redis. That way when containers are made, the code will run with SideKiq and Redis and access the external Postgres Databases.

**The Problem**

Every time I search to try and find a solution, I get results about connecting to a Postgres DB within a Docker Container, or connecting to a locally hosted DB, or a host of other scenarios. I have spent weeks researching this and I am sure that I am missing something simple as it seems like this should be a straight forward situation.

**My development Environment**

- Ruby version: 3.2.1
- Rails version: 7.0.4.2
- Redis: 4.1.4
- DB (1)location: Hosted on Microsoft Azure
- DB (2) location: Hosted on Microsoft Azure

**Code**

`database.yml`

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  primary:
    <<: *default
    url: <%= ENV['DB_URL'] %>
    migrations_paths: db/migrate
  members:
    <<: *default
    url: <%= ENV['MEMBER_DB_URL'] %>
    migrations_paths: db/member_migrate

test:
  primary:
    <<: *default
    database: app_primary_test
    migrations_paths: db/migrate
  members:
    <<: *default
    database: members_test
    migrations_paths: db/member_migrate

production:
  primary:
    <<: *default
    url: <%= ENV['DB_URL'] %>
  members:
    <<: *default
    url: <%= ENV['MEMBER_DB_URL'] %>
```

`Dockerfile`

```
# Use an official Ruby runtime as a parent image
FROM ruby:3.2.1

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    nodejs \
    postgresql-client && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install gems
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN gem install bundler && \
    bundle install --jobs 4

# Copy the application code
COPY . .

# Expose ports
EXPOSE 3000

# Set the entrypoint command
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
  db:
    image: postgres:12
    environment:
      - BUNDLE_WITHOUT=${BUNDLE_WITHOUT}
      - DB_DATABASE=${DB_DATABASE}
      - DB_HOST=${DB_HOST}
      - DB_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - DB_PORT=${DB_PORT}
      - DB_URL=${DB_URL}
      - DB_USERNAME=${DB_USERNAME}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USERNAME}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_DATABASE}
      - MEMBER_DB_DATABASE=${MEMBER_DB_DATABASE}
      - MEMBER_DB_HOST=${MEMBER_DB_HOST}
      - MEMBER_DB_PASSWORD=${MEMBER_DB_PASSWORD}
      - MEMBER_DB_PORT=${MEMBER_DB_PORT}
      - MEMBER_DB_URL=${MEMBER_DB_URL}
      - MEMBER_DB_USERNAME=${MEMBER_DB_USERNAME}
      - DEPLOYMENT_BRANCH=${DEPLOYMENT_BRANCH}
      - MEMBERS_BUCKET_AWS=${MEMBERS_BUCKET_AWS}
      - MAILGUN_API_KEY=${MAILGUN_API_KEY}
      - MAILGUN_DOMAIN=${MAILGUN_DOMAIN}
      - RAILS_ENV=${RAILS_ENV}
      - RAILS_MASTER_KEY=${RAILS_MASTER_KEY}
      - RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY=${RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY}
      - RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY=${RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY}
      - SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_AWS=${SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_AWS}
      - SECRET_KEY_BASE=${SECRET_KEY_BASE}
  redis:
    image: redis:7.0.0
```

And then each of the variables are defined in a `.env` file in the `root` directory along side the `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` files.

**Final Information**

Now, I am not sure if all of those environment variables need to be there, or how secure it is to have them there. (I am used to storing them within the app Settings on Heroku, not within the code itself.)

The `POSTGRES_USER`, `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` and `POSTGRES_DB` I put there because of another StackOverflow answer which made me think that there are system default ENV variable names that need to be used. (Again, not sure if that is the case or not)

The `DB_URL` and `MEMBER_DB_URL` are single strings (again which Heroku uses) that combines the username, password, host, port, etc for connecting to the DB. In short all things that someone would need to gain access to the data. (Security wise that scares me a bit)

(EDIT: Per comment request here are the URLs with sensitive info removed.)

```
DB_URL: postgres://<user_name>:<password>@<server_url>/<db_name>?sslmode=require
MEMBER_DB_URL: postgres://<user_name>:<password>@<server_url>/<member_db_name>?sslmode=require
```

Please Note that I am able to connect to the Azure databases using PgAdmin4 on my local machine via this information and the URL strings are the same as in Heroku and that app can connect to the databases.

**ERROR Message**

Here is the error message when I run Rails console from within the shell.

```
# rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 7.0.4.2)
irb(main):001:0> Member.first
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-7.0.4.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:87:in `rescue in new_client': could not connect to server: No such file or directory (ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished)
        Is the server running locally and accepting               
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
                                                                  
/usr/local/bundle/gems/pg-1.4.5/lib/pg/connection.rb:755:in `connect_start': could not connect to server: No such file or directory (PG::ConnectionBad)                                                             
        Is the server running locally and accepting               
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Here is the error log when I try and pull up `localhost:3000`

```
2023-02-27 09:50:58 => Booting Puma
2023-02-27 09:50:58 => Rails 7.0.4.2 application starting in development 
2023-02-27 09:50:58 => Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
2023-02-27 09:51:00 [1] Puma starting in cluster mode...
2023-02-27 09:51:00 [1] * Version 4.2.1 (ruby 3.2.1-p31), codename: Distant Airhorns
2023-02-27 09:51:00 [1] * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2023-02-27 09:51:00 [1] * Environment: development
2023-02-27 09:51:00 [1] * Process workers: 2
2023-02-27 09:51:00 [1] * Preloading application
2023-02-27 09:51:00 [1] * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
2023-02-27 09:51:00 [1] Use Ctrl-C to stop
2023-02-27 09:51:00 [1] - Worker 1 (pid: 16) booted, phase: 0
2023-02-27 09:51:00 [1] - Worker 0 (pid: 13) booted, phase: 0
2023-02-27 10:31:19 DEPRECATION WARNING: Non-URL-safe CSRF tokens are deprecated. Use 6.1 defaults or above. (called from block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie> at /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.2/lib/action_controller/railtie.rb:80)
2023-02-27 10:31:19 Started GET "/" for 172.20.0.1 at 2023-02-27 17:31:19 +0000
2023-02-27 10:31:19 Cannot render console from 172.20.0.1! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255, ::1
2023-02-27 10:31:19   
2023-02-27 10:31:19 ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (could not connect to server: No such file or directory
2023-02-27 10:31:19     Is the server running locally and accepting
2023-02-27 10:31:19     connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
2023-02-27 10:31:19 ):
2023-02-27 10:31:19   
2023-02-27 10:31:19 activerecord (7.0.4.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:87:in `rescue in new_client'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 activerecord (7.0.4.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:77:in `new_client'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 activerecord (7.0.4.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:37:in `postgresql_connection'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 activerecord (7.0.4.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:656:in `public_send'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 activerecord (7.0.4.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:656:in `new_connection'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 activerecord (7.0.4.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:700:in `checkout_new_connection'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 activerecord (7.0.4.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:679:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 activerecord (7.0.4.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:640:in `acquire_connection'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 activerecord (7.0.4.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:341:in `checkout'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 activerecord (7.0.4.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:181:in `connection'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 activerecord (7.0.4.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_handler.rb:211:in `retrieve_connection'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 activerecord (7.0.4.2) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:313:in `retrieve_connection'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 activerecord (7.0.4.2) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:280:in `connection'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 activerecord (7.0.4.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:613:in `connection'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 activerecord (7.0.4.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:608:in `build_watcher'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 activerecord (7.0.4.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:590:in `block in call'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 activerecord (7.0.4.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:589:in `synchronize'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 activerecord (7.0.4.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:589:in `call'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 actionpack (7.0.4.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 activesupport (7.0.4.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:99:in `run_callbacks'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 actionpack (7.0.4.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 actionpack (7.0.4.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 actionpack (7.0.4.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 actionpack (7.0.4.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:28:in `call'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 web-console (4.2.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:132:in `call_app'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 web-console (4.2.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:19:in `block in call'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 web-console (4.2.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `catch'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 web-console (4.2.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 actionpack (7.0.4.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:26:in `call'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 railties (7.0.4.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:40:in `call_app'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 railties (7.0.4.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:25:in `block in call'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 activesupport (7.0.4.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `block in tagged'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 activesupport (7.0.4.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:37:in `tagged'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 activesupport (7.0.4.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `tagged'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 railties (7.0.4.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:25:in `call'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 sprockets-rails (3.4.2) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 actionpack (7.0.4.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:93:in `call'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 actionpack (7.0.4.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:26:in `call'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 rack (2.2.6.2) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 rack (2.2.6.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 activesupport (7.0.4.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 actionpack (7.0.4.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 rack-livereload (0.3.17) lib/rack/livereload.rb:23:in `_call'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 rack-livereload (0.3.17) lib/rack/livereload.rb:14:in `call'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 actionpack (7.0.4.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:23:in `call'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 rack (2.2.6.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 actionpack (7.0.4.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:137:in `call'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 webpacker (5.4.4) lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:25:in `perform_request'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 rack-proxy (0.7.6) lib/rack/proxy.rb:87:in `call'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 railties (7.0.4.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:530:in `call'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 puma (4.2.1) lib/puma/configuration.rb:228:in `call'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 puma (4.2.1) lib/puma/server.rb:667:in `handle_request'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 puma (4.2.1) lib/puma/server.rb:470:in `process_client'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 puma (4.2.1) lib/puma/server.rb:328:in `block in run'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 puma (4.2.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:134:in `block in spawn_thread'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 #<Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL: Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:35729 (Cannot assign requested address - connect(2) for "localhost" port 35729)>
2023-02-27 10:31:19 2023-02-27 17:31:19 +0000: Rack app error handling request { GET / }
2023-02-27 10:31:19 #<Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL: Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:35729 (Cannot assign requested address - connect(2) for "localhost" port 35729)>
2023-02-27 10:31:19 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/net/http.rb:1271:in `initialize'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/net/http.rb:1271:in `open'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/net/http.rb:1271:in `block in connect'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 /usr/local/bundle/gems/timeout-0.3.2/lib/timeout.rb:189:in `block in timeout'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 /usr/local/bundle/gems/timeout-0.3.2/lib/timeout.rb:196:in `timeout'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/net/http.rb:1269:in `connect'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/net/http.rb:1248:in `do_start'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/net/http.rb:1237:in `start'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/net/http.rb:1817:in `request'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/net/http.rb:1797:in `send_request'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-livereload-0.3.17/lib/rack/livereload/body_processor.rb:50:in `use_vendored?'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-livereload-0.3.17/lib/rack/livereload/body_processor.rb:101:in `livereload_source'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 (erb):14:in `block (2 levels) in process!'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/erb.rb:429:in `eval'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/erb.rb:429:in `result'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-livereload-0.3.17/lib/rack/livereload/body_processor.rb:78:in `block (2 levels) in process!'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb:313:in `block in gsub!'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb:311:in `gsub!'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb:311:in `gsub!'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-livereload-0.3.17/lib/rack/livereload/body_processor.rb:78:in `block in process!'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-livereload-0.3.17/lib/rack/livereload/body_processor.rb:76:in `each'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-livereload-0.3.17/lib/rack/livereload/body_processor.rb:76:in `process!'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-livereload-0.3.17/lib/rack/livereload.rb:28:in `_call'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-livereload-0.3.17/lib/rack/livereload.rb:14:in `call'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:23:in `call'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.2.6.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:137:in `call'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 /usr/local/bundle/gems/webpacker-5.4.4/lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:25:in `perform_request'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-proxy-0.7.6/lib/rack/proxy.rb:87:in `call'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:530:in `call'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-4.2.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:228:in `call'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-4.2.1/lib/puma/server.rb:667:in `handle_request'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-4.2.1/lib/puma/server.rb:470:in `process_client'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-4.2.1/lib/puma/server.rb:328:in `block in run'
2023-02-27 10:31:19 /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-4.2.1/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:134:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

**Question**

What am I missing? Am I not declaring the ENV correctly for Docker? Does it have to do with Docker's unique networking setup? I would think this should be straight forward as I am sure I am not the only one that will have multiple Docker containers needing access to a centralized database. Please help! I'll buy you a coffee ;-) Or send out good thoughts and vibes to you.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I've read your whole question, but it's not clear to me what exactly is the problem. Are you getting an error when you try to create a DB client in Ruby?

Comment: I am sorry about that @Anton, I have added the error to my question. Also, in adding the error code, I noticed that the environment being loaded was "development" and that database is supposed to be on the local machine, not the Azure stored database. I updated the `database.yml` file, but still getting the same error.

Comment: It seems like the app ignores your `database.yml` and tries to find a DB locally. Neither in prod nor in dev configurations the DB will be local. It may help if you share your DB_URL and MEMBER_DB_URL (with sensitive parts removed).

Comment: @Anton, I added that information to the question.

Comment: I have  been on same error on my local enviroment with windows and wsl linux, and my error was on the settings of database.yml, should be port, host properties, and check the postgres (accept "localhost") file  and pg_hba file accept local host

Comment: Thank you both for your advise. I was able to figure out what was wrong and posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out where I was going wrong. It's within my `docker-compose.yml` file. I was setting the environment variables (ENV) under the database service, not the web service. So, even though the database had the values needed to connect, the web app didn't and so the `database.yml` file wasn't getting the connection values it needed.

Now, I thought that it would get the values like it does in the development environment, from the `.env` file, but just like they needed to be listed in the Heroku settings, they needed to be listed here. (Though now I am having another issue, which I will post a new question. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75620376/getting-a-failed-to-open-tcp-connection-to-localhost35729-error-after-deployi))

**Explanation**

Within the `docker-compose.yml` file you basically state what is going to be "running" within the docker container. Now, I put "running" in quotes because that is not technically the case, which I will explain as we step through the file.

*First the setup*

Basic `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    
  db:
    
  redis:
```

This tells the Docker Composer what version of composer to use (version 3) and that there will be 3 services within the container: a web app, a database connection and a Redis data store.

Next, you need to explain information about each.

Expanded `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3100 -b '0.0.0.0'
    ports:
      - "3100:3100"
    environment:
      # Put ENV values here
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
  db:
    image: postgres:12
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      # Put Connection Variables Here
  redis:
    image: redis:7.0.0
```

Let's work from the bottom up:

*Under the `redis` service*

- The information here states that the Docker Composer should grab a Redis image from online to create the Redis data store (ie version 7.0.0).

*Under the `db` service*

- The information here states that the Docker Composer should grab a PostgreSQL image from online to create the database and/or know what the database structure should look like (ie version 12). This is where the "not technically running" comes into play. There isn't a PostgreSQL database running within the container, but the information here is needed because the webapp that is running depends on the connection. (More on that later)
- It then states what port that database will be accessed by (ie 5432), if the database is found within the container; otherwise it is not needed.
- And then it states the variables needed to access the database.

*Under the `web` service*

- The information here tells the Docker Composer to build from the `Dockerfile`
- Then to run the server. NOTE: I designated port 3100 as 3000 was running the Rails app on my machine rather than the Docker container; but, you can change that to 3000 if you wish.
- Then it states what ports to release for access to the webapp (Should be the same as you stated in the above step)
- Then it states any ENV values needed within the app.
- Then it states what the app depends on, ie a database and the Redis data store. If these things are not accessible, the container and web app will fail.

So, my final `docker-compose.yml` file looks like this:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3100 -b '0.0.0.0'
    ports:
      - "3100:3100"
    environment:
      RAILS_MASTER_KEY: ${RAILS_MASTER_KEY}
      SECRET_KEY_BASE: ${SECRET_KEY_BASE}
      
      RAILS_ENV: production
      DEPLOYMENT_BRANCH: main
      BUNDLE_WITHOUT: development,test

      DB_HOST: ${DB_HOST}
      DB_PORT: ${DB_PORT}

      PRIMARY_DB_NAME: ${PRIMARY_DB_NAME}
      PRIMARY_DB_USERNAME: ${PRIMARY_DB_USERNAME}
      PRIMARY_DB_PASSWORD: ${PRIMARY_DB_PASSWORD}

      MEMBER_DB_NAME: ${MEMBER_DB_NAME}
      MEMBER_DB_USERNAME: ${MEMBER_DB_USERNAME}
      MEMBER_DB_PASSWORD: ${MEMBER_DB_PASSWORD}
      
      ACCESS_KEY_ID_AWS: ${ACCESS_KEY_ID_AWS}
      SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_AWS: ${SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_AWS}
      AVATAR_BUCKET_AWS: ${AVATAR_BUCKET_AWS}
      
      MAILGUN_API_KEY: ${MAILGUN_API_KEY}
      MAILGUN_DOMAIN: ${MAILGUN_DOMAIN}
    
      RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY: ${RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY}
      RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY: ${RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY}
    depends_on:
      - db_primary
      - db_member
      - redis
  db_primary:
    image: postgres:12
    environment:
      POSTGRES_HOST: ${DB_HOST}
      POSTGRES_PORT: 5432
      POSTGRES_NAME: ${PRIMARY_DB_NAME}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${PRIMARY_DB_USERNAME}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${PRIMARY_DB_PASSWORD}
  db_member:
    image: postgres:12
    environment:
      POSTGRES_HOST: ${DB_HOST}
      POSTGRES_PORT: 5432
      POSTGRES_NAME: ${MEMBER_DB_NAME}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${MEMBER_DB_USERNAME}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${MEMBER_DB_PASSWORD}
  redis:
    image: redis:7.0.0
```

**Conclusion**

Making these changes allowed my app to actually run and deploy to Azure, even though I am now getting a different error. But, on my local machine and when I log into the shell, I am able to run a Rails console and see the database data; so I know this issue is fixed. Now onto the next that I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75620376/getting-a-failed-to-open-tcp-connection-to-localhost35729-error-after-deployi). LOL.

**Happy Coding!**