# Getting a ‘Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:35729’ error after deploying a RoR Docker image to Azure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, azure, docker

## Explanation of the Issue

I have a Ruby on Rails application that I have been able to Dockerize. It works fine on my computer. When I push it to Azure I get the following error:

`Puma caught this error: Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:35729 (Cannot assign requested address - connect(2) for "localhost" port 35729) (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL)`

## Development Environment

- Ruby version 3.2.1
- Rails version 7.0.4.2
- Docker version 20.10.22, build 3a2c30b
- Docker Compose version v2.15.1

## Detailed Code

`Gemfile`

```
############################################################################################
### Setup
############################################################################################

source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#%7Brepo%7D.git" }

ruby '3.2.1'

############################################################################################
### Preset Gems
############################################################################################

gem 'rails',        '~> 7.0.4.2'
gem 'bundler',      '>= 2.1.4'
gem 'pg',           '>= 1.1.4',  '< 2.0'
gem 'puma',         '~> 4.2.1'
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 6.0.0'
gem 'webpacker',    '~> 5.4.0'
gem 'uglifier',     '>= 4.2.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'turbolinks',   '~> 5.2.1'
gem 'jbuilder',     '~> 2.9.1'
gem 'bootsnap',     '>= 1.4.5',             require: false

# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production

gem 'redis', '~> 4.1.3'

############################################################################################
### Development Gems
############################################################################################

group :development, :test do
    gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
    gem 'capybara',               '~> 3.35.3'
    gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
    gem 'web-console',            '>= 4.0.1'
    gem 'listen',                 '~> 3.2'
    gem 'spring'
    gem 'spring-watcher-listen',  '~> 2.0.1'
    
    # Check for N+1 queries
    gem 'bullet'

    # Live Reload of files in browser during development
    gem "guard", ">= 2.16.1", :require => false
    gem "guard-livereload",  :require => false
    gem "rack-livereload"
    gem "rb-fsevent",        :require => false
end

group :test do
    gem 'webdrivers'
end

############################################################################################
### My Global Gems
############################################################################################

# Friendly URLs

gem 'friendly_id',            '~> 5.3.0', require: "friendly_id"

# Design Gems
gem 'font-awesome-rails'                    # Text Icons
gem 'redcarpet',              '~> 3.5.0'    # Markdown

# Image processing and storage
gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'
gem "aws-sdk-s3", require: false

# For sending emails
gem 'mailgun-ruby'

# Spam fighter
gem 'recaptcha', require: "recaptcha/rails"

# for .env file
gem 'dotenv-rails'

############################################################################################
### Application Specific Gems
############################################################################################

gem 'devise', '4.8.1'
gem 'doorkeeper'

gem 'tzinfo-data'
gem "matrix", "~> 0.4.2"
```

`Dockerfile`

```
# Use an official Ruby runtime as a parent image
FROM ruby:3.2.1

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    bash \
    bash-completion \
    git \
    less \
    libffi-dev \
    tzdata \
    postgresql-client \
    nodejs \
    npm \
    yarn && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/\*

# Setup shortcuts for bash commands
RUN echo "alias ll='ls -alF'" >> $HOME/.bashrc
RUN echo "alias la='ls -A'" >> $HOME/.bashrc
RUN echo "alias l='ls -CF'" >> $HOME/.bashrc
RUN echo "alias q='exit'" >> $HOME/.bashrc
RUN echo "alias c='clear'" >> $HOME/.bashrc
RUN echo "alias cd..='cd ../'" >> $HOME/.bashrc
RUN echo "alias ..='cd ../'" >> $HOME/.bashrc
RUN echo "alias ...='cd ../../'" >> $HOME/.bashrc

# Install gems
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN gem install bundler && \
bundle install --jobs 4

# Set Default ENV values
    # Allows static files to be available
ENV RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES true
    # Sends log files to terminal rather than to production.log file
ENV RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT true

# Copy the application code
COPY . .

# Upgrade Yarn
RUN npm install --global yarn

# Precompile the assets
RUN bundle exec rake DATABASE_URL=postgresql:does_not_exist assets:precompile

# Expose ports
    # Main Site Port
EXPOSE 3000
    # LiveReload Port
EXPOSE 35729

# Set the entrypoint command
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3"

services:
    web:
        build: .
        command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'

        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
        environment:
            RAILS_MASTER_KEY: ${RAILS_MASTER_KEY}
            SECRET_KEY_BASE: ${SECRET_KEY_BASE}

            RAILS_ENV: ${RAILS_ENV}
            DEPLOYMENT_BRANCH: ${DEPLOYMENT_BRANCH}
            BUNDLE_WITHOUT: ${BUNDLE_WITHOUT}

            DB_HOST: ${DB_HOST}
            DB_PORT: ${DB_PORT}
            DB_NAME: ${DB_NAME}
            DB_USERNAME: ${DB_USERNAME}
            DB_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
  
            ACCESS_KEY_ID_AWS: ${ACCESS_KEY_ID_AWS}
            SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_AWS: ${SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_AWS}
            HEIS_SOMA_BUCKET_AWS: ${HEIS_SOMA_BUCKET_AWS}
  
            MAILGUN_API_KEY: ${MAILGUN_API_KEY}
            MAILGUN_DOMAIN: ${MAILGUN_DOMAIN}

            RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY: ${RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY}
            RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY: ${RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY}
        depends_on:
            - db
            - redis

    db:
        image: postgres:12
        environment:
            POSTGRES_HOST: ${DB_HOST}
            POSTGRES_PORT: 5432
            POSTGRES_NAME: ${DB_NAME}
            POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
    redis:
        image: redis:7.0.0
```

## Detailed Error Message

**Displayed in web browser when trying to access website**

```
Puma caught this error: Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:35729 (Cannot assign requested address - connect(2) for "localhost" port 35729) (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL)     
/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/net/http.rb:1271:in 'initialize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/net/http.rb:1271:in 'open'        
/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/net/http.rb:1271:in 'block in connect'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/timeout-0.3.2/lib/timeout.rb:189:in 'block in timeout'     
/usr/local/bundle/gems/timeout-0.3.2/lib/timeout.rb:196:in 'timeout'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/net/http.rb:1269:in 'connect'     
/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/net/http.rb:1248:in 'do_start'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/net/http.rb:1237:in 'start'     
/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/net/http.rb:1817:in 'request'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/net/http.rb:1797:in 'send_request' /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-livereload-0.3.17/lib/rack/livereload/body_processor.rb:50:in 'use_vendored?'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-livereload-0.3.17/lib/rack/livereload/body_processor.rb:101:in livereload_source' (erb):14:in 'block (2 levels) in process!'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/erb.rb:429:in 'eval' /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/erb.rb:429:in result'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-livereload-0.3.17/lib/rack/livereload/body_processor.rb:78:in 'block (2 levels) in process!' /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb:313:in 'block in gsub!'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb:311:in 'gsub!' /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb:311:in 'gsub!'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-livereload-0.3.17/lib/rack/livereload/body_processor.rb:78:in 'block in process!' /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-livereload-0.3.17/lib/rack/livereload/body_processor.rb:76:in 'each'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-livereload-0.3.17/lib/rack/livereload/body_processor.rb:76:in 'process!' /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-livereload-0.3.17/lib/rack/livereload.rb:28:in '_call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-livereload-0.3.17/lib/rack/livereload.rb:14:in 'call' /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:23:in 'call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.2.6.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in 'call' /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:137:in 'call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/webpacker-5.4.4/lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:25:in 'perform_request' /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-proxy-0.7.6/lib/rack/proxy.rb:87:in 'call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:530:in 'call' /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-4.2.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:228:in 'call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-4.2.1/lib/puma/server.rb:667:in 'handle_request' /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-4.2.1/lib/puma/server.rb:470:in 'process_client'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-4.2.1/lib/puma/server.rb:328:in 'block in run' /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-4.2.1/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:134:in 'block in spawn_thread'
```

**Console Log**

```
2023-03-02T17:14:24.321696598Z => Booting Puma 2023-03-02T17:14:24.321739798Z => Rails 7.0.4.2 application starting in development 2023-03-02T17:14:24.321744398Z => Run 'bin/rails server --help' for more startup options 2023-03-02T17:14:27.726467117Z [1] Puma starting in cluster mode... 2023-03-02T17:14:27.734817505Z [1] * Version 4.2.1 (ruby 3.2.1-p31), codename: Distant Airhorns 2023-03-02T17:14:27.734833205Z [1] * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5 2023-03-02T17:14:27.734837505Z [1] * Environment: development 2023-03-02T17:14:27.735587304Z [1] * Process workers: 2 2023-03-02T17:14:27.735600403Z [1] * Preloading application 2023-03-02T17:14:27.763011363Z [1] * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000 2023-03-02T17:14:27.763026563Z [1] Use Ctrl-C to stop 2023-03-02T17:14:27.872657999Z [1] - Worker 1 (pid: 15) booted, phase: 0 2023-03-02T17:14:27.901011557Z [1] - Worker 0 (pid: 12) booted, phase: 0 2023-03-02T17:14:28.691320078Z [ActionDispatch::HostAuthorization::DefaultResponseApp] Blocked host: 169.254.131.2 2023-03-02T17:14:29.464706224Z DEPRECATION WARNING: Non-URL-safe CSRF tokens are deprecated. Use 6.1 defaults or above. (called from block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie> at /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.2/lib/action_controller/railtie.rb:80) 2023-03-02T17:14:29.616891697Z Started GET "/" for 169.254.131.1 at 2023-03-02 17:14:29 +0000 2023-03-02T17:14:29.627506881Z Cannot render console from 169.254.131.1! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255, ::1 2023-03-02T17:14:29.985157747Z [1m[36mActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Pluck (8.2ms)[0m [1m[34mSELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC[0m 2023-03-02T17:14:30.254852845Z Processing by PagesController#home as HTML 2023-03-02T17:14:30.379776659Z [1m[36mSetting Load (1.6ms)[0m [1m[34mSELECT "settings".* FROM "settings" ORDER BY "settings"."id" ASC LIMIT $1[0m [["LIMIT", 1]] 2023-03-02T17:14:30.379804659Z ↳ app/controllers/concerns/settings_concern.rb:9:in'load_settings'
2023-03-02T17:14:30.544065014Z Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
2023-03-02T17:14:30.544530813Z Rendering pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application
2023-03-02T17:14:30.612869211Z Rendered devise/shared/\_login_card_and_logo.html.erb (Duration: 66.0ms | Allocations: 2887)
2023-03-02T17:14:30.622557996Z Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 78.1ms | Allocations: 4183)
2023-03-02T17:14:30.633724680Z Rendered shared/\_google_analytics.html.erb (Duration: 0.5ms | Allocations: 168)
2023-03-02T17:14:30.644208364Z Rendered shared/\_deploy_date.html.erb (Duration: 0.5ms | Allocations: 83)
2023-03-02T17:14:31.510677272Z \[Webpacker\] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
2023-03-02T17:14:31.518397660Z Rendered layouts/\_application_header.html.erb (Duration: 894.4ms | Allocations: 35211)
2023-03-02T17:14:31.548136016Z Rendered shared/\_sign_in_button.html.erb (Duration: 18.0ms | Allocations: 1272)
2023-03-02T17:14:31.548545215Z Rendered shared/\_links_header.html.erb (Duration: 27.9ms | Allocations: 2723)
2023-03-02T17:14:31.548711715Z Rendered shared/\_navbar_chooser.html.erb (Duration: 29.5ms | Allocations: 3021)
2023-03-02T17:14:31.550373412Z Rendered layouts/\_template_chooser_header.html.erb (Duration: 1.1ms | Allocations: 1111)
2023-03-02T17:14:31.560219898Z Rendered shared/\_alerts.html.erb (Duration: 0.6ms | Allocations: 330)
2023-03-02T17:14:31.579166469Z Rendered shared/\_modals.html.erb (Duration: 0.2ms | Allocations: 72)
2023-03-02T17:14:31.587108358Z Rendered shared/\_logos_reftagger.html.erb (Duration: 0.4ms | Allocations: 103)
2023-03-02T17:14:31.587496157Z Rendered layouts/\_application_footer.html.erb (Duration: 17.4ms | Allocations: 2082)
2023-03-02T17:14:31.587732757Z Rendered layouts/\_template_chooser_footer.html.erb (Duration: 18.4ms | Allocations: 2473)
2023-03-02T17:14:31.588024756Z Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 1043.7ms | Allocations: 47319)
2023-03-02T17:14:31.588592755Z Completed 200 OK in 1333ms (Views: 1052.8ms | ActiveRecord: 48.0ms | Allocations: 74721)
2023-03-02T17:14:31.588602455Z
2023-03-02T17:14:31.588605655Z
2023-03-02T17:14:31.608195126Z #\<Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL: Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:35729 (Cannot assign requested address - connect(2) for "localhost" port 35729)\>
2023-03-02T17:14:31.608214826Z 2023-03-02 17:14:31 +0000: Rack app error handling request { GET / }
2023-03-02T17:14:31.608218526Z #\<Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL: Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:35729 (Cannot assign requested address - connect(2) for "localhost" port 35729)\>
2023-03-02T17:14:31.608221626Z /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/net/http.rb:1271:in 'initialize' 2023-03-02T17:14:31.608224426Z /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/net/http.rb:1271:in 'open'
2023-03-02T17:14:31.608227126Z /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/net/http.rb:1271:in 'block in connect' 2023-03-02T17:14:31.608229926Z /usr/local/bundle/gems/timeout-0.3.2/lib/timeout.rb:189:in 'block in timeout'
2023-03-02T17:14:31.608232726Z /usr/local/bundle/gems/timeout-0.3.2/lib/timeout.rb:196:in 'timeout' 2023-03-02T17:14:31.608235326Z /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/net/http.rb:1269:in 'connect'
2023-03-02T17:14:31.608238026Z /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/net/http.rb:1248:in 'do_start' 2023-03-02T17:14:31.608240726Z /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/net/http.rb:1237:in 'start'
2023-03-02T17:14:31.608243526Z /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/net/http.rb:1817:in 'request' 2023-03-02T17:14:31.608246126Z /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/net/http.rb:1797:in 'send_request'
2023-03-02T17:14:31.608248826Z /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-livereload-0.3.17/lib/rack/livereload/body_processor.rb:50:in 'use_vendored?' 2023-03-02T17:14:31.608251626Z /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-livereload-0.3.17/lib/rack/livereload/body_processor.rb:101:in 'livereload_source'
2023-03-02T17:14:31.608261526Z (erb):14:in 'block (2 levels) in process!' 2023-03-02T17:14:31.608264226Z /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/erb.rb:429:in 'eval'
2023-03-02T17:14:31.608266926Z /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/erb.rb:429:in 'result' 2023-03-02T17:14:31.608269526Z /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-livereload-0.3.17/lib/rack/livereload/body_processor.rb:78:in 'block (2 levels) in process!'
2023-03-02T17:14:31.608272426Z /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb:313:in 'block in gsub!' 2023-03-02T17:14:31.608275226Z /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb:311:in 'gsub!'
2023-03-02T17:14:31.608278026Z /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb:311:in 'gsub!' 2023-03-02T17:14:31.608280726Z /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-livereload-0.3.17/lib/rack/livereload/body_processor.rb:78:in 'block in process!'
2023-03-02T17:14:31.608283526Z /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-livereload-0.3.17/lib/rack/livereload/body_processor.rb:76:in 'each' 2023-03-02T17:14:31.608286826Z /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-livereload-0.3.17/lib/rack/livereload/body_processor.rb:76:in 'process!'
2023-03-02T17:14:31.608289626Z /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-livereload-0.3.17/lib/rack/livereload.rb:28:in '_call' 2023-03-02T17:14:31.608292326Z /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-livereload-0.3.17/lib/rack/livereload.rb:14:in 'call'
2023-03-02T17:14:31.608295026Z /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:23:in 'call' 2023-03-02T17:14:31.608297726Z /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.2.6.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in 'call'
2023-03-02T17:14:31.608350326Z /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:137:in 'call' 2023-03-02T17:14:31.608354326Z /usr/local/bundle/gems/webpacker-5.4.4/lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:25:in 'perform_request'
2023-03-02T17:14:31.608357126Z /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-proxy-0.7.6/lib/rack/proxy.rb:87:in 'call' 2023-03-02T17:14:31.608359726Z /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.4.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:530:in 'call'
2023-03-02T17:14:31.608362426Z /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-4.2.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:228:in 'call' 2023-03-02T17:14:31.608365126Z /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-4.2.1/lib/puma/server.rb:667:in 'handle_request'
2023-03-02T17:14:31.608367826Z /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-4.2.1/lib/puma/server.rb:470:in 'process_client' 2023-03-02T17:14:31.608370526Z /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-4.2.1/lib/puma/server.rb:328:in 'block in run'
2023-03-02T17:14:31.608373126Z /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-4.2.1/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:134:in 'block in spawn_thread'
```

## What I tried

I tried to add `EXPOSE 35729` to the `Dockerfile` to open the port. But, that didn't work. I am unsure why the Dockerized app works on my local machine but not when deployed.

## Reviewing the Logs

Looking at the console log it does look like the index page completes with a 200 code and then the Error is reached and that is displayed.

Also, the log looks to be referencing the `rack-livereload` gem, which is located in my development environment within my `Gemfile`. I tried to comment out and re-run bundle. But, that threw a lot of errors as 'livereload' is mentioned a lot in the code.

## What I was expecting

I was expecting the Docker image to work just as it does on my local machine